# What is browser agent GTB7.4?

Tags: iis, logging, browser, agent

In my IIS logs, some of the entries say Mozilla/4.0(compatible...;+GTB7.4;...).  I am a curious/suspicious person and would like to find out what "GTB7.4" means.  No useful info on goog, bing or SO.  It seems to be some add-on for MSIE 8.0.  What is it?

Comment: I wish some of these stack overflow moderators would stop closing great questions. Your question seems very applicable to me and fine. I just saw the same thing in a web log and wondered the same thing. Devs are looking at this and it is a valid development question.

Comment: After getting down-voted and [closed], I considered removing this one.  However, I rely on SO for answers and when there is nada on goog and bing, I figured somebody, somewhere is going to find this info useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fragment of the User agent that tells you that particular browser has the Google Toolbar v. 7.4 installed.
From the fragment you posted -

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible

it might be Internet Explorer 8 or less.

References:

- [User agent GTB or GTB5 is the Google Toolbar](http://gingerjoos.com/blog/technology/user-agent-gtb-or-gtb5-is-the-google-toolbar)
- [Remove or ignore GTB (Google Toolbar) entry from the HTTP_USER_AGENT](http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/remove-or-ignore-gtb-google-toolbar-entry-from-the-http-782317.html)